# How to prevent the last number override the array?

Tags: c#

So I am trying to sort the fractions with the fraction class as array. Even though I think something is wrong too with my operators, I can't test it since the output I give is always the last number that overrides the whole array and I don't really know what is causing this.

The main class:(sort methods excluded)

```
        int m;
        int n; static Fraction fraction = new Fraction();//edited
        int denominator;
        int numerator;
        Fraction[] frac;//fraction
        string l = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] split = l.Split(' ');
        m = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
        n = Int32.Parse(split[1]);
        frac = new Fraction[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            string o = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] split2 = o.Split(' ');
            denominator= Int32.Parse(split2[0]);
            numerator= Int32.Parse(split2[1]);
            fraction.denominator= denominator;
            fraction.numerator= numerator;
            frac[i] = fraction;//put the numbers in the
                               //array
        }
        if (m < n)
            SelectionSort(frac);
        else
            QuickSort(frac, 0, m - 1);

        for (int i =0; i< m; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(frac[i]);
        }
```

And this is the fraction class:

```
    int denominator;
    int numerator;

    public int denominator
    {
        get { return denominator; }
        set { denominator= value; }
    }

    public int numerator
    {
        get { return numerator; }
        set { numerator= value; }
    }

    public static bool operator <(Fraction left, Fraction right)
    {
        var diff = left.denominator* right.numerator- right.numerator* left.denominator;
        return diff < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Fraction left, Fraction right)
    {
        var difference= left.denominator* right.numerator- right.numerator* left.denominator;
        return !(difference> 0);
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.denominator, this.numerator);
    }
```

I can't even test my operators(never used til now) whether they are working or not since the array is wrong. Any suggestions how to find the error?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Where is `fraction` declared?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that in the code but fraction is in the main class declared: static Fraction fraction = new Fraction();
I will add that in the code

Comment: Why did you declare it as static?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `for` loop. You're always editing the same `Fraction` object over and over (and your array is filled with copies of the same object).

Change your code to instantiate a new `Fraction` at each iteration of your loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
 {
      string o = Console.ReadLine();
      string[] split2 = o.Split(' ');
      denominator= Int32.Parse(split2[0]);
      numerator= Int32.Parse(split2[1]);

      var fraction = new Fraction(); // Added line
      fraction.denominator= denominator;
      fraction.numerator= numerator;
      frac[i] = fraction;//put the numbers in the array
 }
```